# Item versions to create by date

Tags: solr, itemservice, sitecore-search

We have requirement to show some text content (rich text field) based on revision date updated (date field). Latest updated content (sorted by date in descending) will be shown at the top . So content authoring will like , next month when I want to create new content with different date , he/she will be interested in creating new content and publish, so the webpage should take care of showing new record at the top and old ones at the bottom in descending order

Maximum number of records could go up to 50-80 in a folder.

Trying to find best possible solution to create these kind of items in sitecore.

Note- These data will be be fetched by search API(using solr, Sitecore version 10.3) currently identified solution is:

Maintain same item version history to show different records

Question
1)-can solr can return all versions of an item and

2)any other drawback of this aproach)
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, by default Solr will not return all versions of the item. But it's not really Solr related, it's how Sitecore publishing and `web` database works.

When you publish an item, it only published the latest publishable version of the item is being transferred to the `web` database, and all the other versions of that item (if they were in the `web` database when publishing started) will be removed from `web` database. And that latest publishable item will be indexed in Solr.

But from what I understood, what you need is only to show the latest version of some items, ordered by date. And that your content authors will prepare those new versions and publish them at some point. With that in mind, I think it's all doable and you don't need any customization for that. Just make sure that:

- your content authors will prepare multiple versions of items and set the Publishing Restrictions of items to only publish given version from certain date ( https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/103/sitecore-experience-platform/set-up-publishing-restrictions-for-an-item.html )
- code will order items using Sitecore Content Search Api by date and render returned results appropriately.